# Akka receive block

Tags: akka

In Erlang it is possible to send the message and wait for desired response in the next line of code inside my function. This makes it easy to put together workflow logic (orchestration logic) in a single function. Can I do the same thing with akka java?

It seems that all the replies are coming into a onRecieve callback. This means that I can never put my workflow logic into one function and as soon I send a message to an actor I would need to get the answer from the actor in a different function which is onRecieve. This again kills my one function warraping my workflow logic. Is this the case? if so, do I have the same problem with akka scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do the exact same thing in Akka, since this is the single most problematic Erlang feature: It leads to memory leaks and bad performance.

However, you can:

A) Spawn a new Actor to handle the conversational logic

B) Use ask/? to deal with the reply

C) Use the Stash feature to avoid handling some messages until some condition is met

Comment: Thanks for your response. Two more questions? Would you please elaborate why that Erlang feature cause memory leak? Any link for this? On a completely different note, do you know what is the most minimal java embedded (ME vs SE) that I need to use for akka to work?

Comment: "What happens when a message doesn’t match any of the clauses in a receive statement? It remains in the process mailbox indefinitely, causing a memory leakage that over time could also cause the runtime system to run out of memory and crash. Not handling unknown messages should therefore be treated as a bug. Either these messages should not have been sent to this process in the first place, or they should be handled, possibly just by being retrieved from the mailbox and ignored." - http://bit.ly/RDO6Hf

Comment: Make sense. Since you are an expert, would you please address what is the most minimal java embedded (ME vs SE) that I need run akka on top of it?

Comment: I am no expert on Java ME so I wouldn't know. I do know that people are running Akka on Android though.

Comment: It looks to me like Stash has the risk that newly-received messages could be interleaved with unstashed messages, so message ordering (from the same sender) could be disrupted.

Comment: Is this anecdotal evidence or just skepticism?